# AxWindowsMediaPlayer not firing any events

Tags: c#, .net, windows-media-player, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have an application which hosts an AxWindowsMediaPlayer in a UserControl in a .NET Windows Forms application.

I have added event listeners to a number of events, including CurrentItemChange, ModeChange and StatusChange.

I set the playlist, and it plays the playlist fine. But none of my event handler functions are being called.

This is frustrating, because it's failing in my production application. But I have written a separate smaller application, and the events are fired without problems.

Does anyone know what could cause the Windows Media Player to stop firing events?

It appears I'm not the first person to encounter this.

- [WMP11 COM component events](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29646772/wmp11-com-component-events.aspx)
- [Windows Media Player Nightmare](http://www.windowsdevelop.com/windows-forms-general/axwindowsmediaplayer-nightmare-34077.shtml)
- [Windows Forms Issue](http://www.ms-windows.info/Help/axwmplibaxwindowsmediaplayer-24799.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following the advice [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29646772/wmp11-com-component-events.aspx):

> Solution is simple. Just remove and
>   add again references to AxWMPLib and
>   WMPLib in your project (I am using
>   VS2005).

And now it works. I'm glad that I can get on with my work, but it's an unsatisfactory solution.

If somebody can tell me why the defect happened, and why removing and adding the references fixed it, I'll give him/her the correct answer mark.